# get the size of a PostgreSQL Database in Java

Tags: java, postgresql

i have a spring boot Web application with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate and a want to write a Java handler  to check in time intervals the fill level of my postgresql database and delete old data accordingly. for example if it reach a max of 10 GB the database has to delete the old data. Is there any Java Library or any suggestion for this purpose? I found only SELECT statements to perform directly on the PostgreSQL Database (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)

Comment: Just run `select pg_database_size('your_db')` through JDBC. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE

Comment: thanks that solved my problem!